# Null reference in java

Tags: java

I have a piece of code for which i have to know how memory is allocated

```
public class Demo {

public void checkNullReference(){
    ConsumerName name =  null;
    addReference(name);
    System.out.println(name.getConsumerName());
}

public void addReference(ConsumerName name){
    name = new ConsumerName();
    name.setConsumerName("KRISHNA");
}

public static void main(String []args){
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    demo.checkNullReference();
}
}
```

The code is giving null pointer exception i have given a refrence of object to method and there i am allocating new object to it and setting name  if i rewrite the method then every thing is working as expected.

```
public void checkNullReference(){
    ConsumerName name =  new ConsumerName();
    addReference(name);
    System.out.println(name.getConsumerName());
}
```

Comment: Say after me: "Java is *always* Call By Value". This means that re-assignment to a parameter *does not* affect any variables "passed" by the caller.

Comment: If you call a method on a null object you will get Null pointer exception.

Comment: The `name=new ConsumerName()` creates an object of consumerName but it would be  scoped to the method `addRef()` hence when you try to retrieve the value of it in menthod checknullref() it goves null exception.. Java is pass by value. :-)

Comment: Because ... it's really a pointer, passed by value, and assigning a value in a method to a local variable does nothing outside of that method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot change a reference in a calling method from the called method. Thus, with this code:

```
public void checkNullReference(){
    ConsumerName name =  null;
    addReference(name);
    System.out.println(name.getConsumerName());
}
```

`name` will still be `null` after the call to `addReference(name)`, regardless of what `addReference` does with its formal argument.

You can redesign `addReference` to *return* an instance of `ConsumerName`. While you're at it, you can delete the argument, since it is ignored. The result could be:

```
public void checkNullReference(){
    ConsumerName name =  addReference();
    System.out.println(name.getConsumerName());
}

public ConsumerName addReference(){
    ConsumerName name = new ConsumerName();
    name.setConsumerName("KRISHNA");
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling addReference() method with a null as input so .. there is no pass by reference happening and ConsumerName is newly getting allocated with in addReference() its scope will remain with in the method only. So you modify your code to return the new instance of ConsumerName .

```
public class Demo {

public void checkNullReference(){
    ConsumerName name =  null;
    name = addReference(name);
    System.out.println(name.getConsumerName());
}

public ConsumerName addReference(ConsumerName name){
    name = new ConsumerName();
    name.setConsumerName("KRISHNA");
    return name ;
}

public static void main(String []args){
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    demo.checkNullReference();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes it seems that approach described by @Vamsi is the right approach. we can omit one line as ConsumerName name =  addReference(name);. We have to store the reference returned by the method

Comment: This helps me: **You are calling addReference() method with a null as input**

Answer (score 1):

Always remember, java uses pass-by-value. When you do

```
name = new ConsumerName();
name.setConsumerName("KRISHNA");
```

it just simply creates a new local object which locate inside addReference function stack. So, as soon as the function returned, you lost that object. In another word, your ConsumerName object inside checkNullReference is not the same as the ConsumerName object inside AddReference.